# Opening folder from a cell that contains the path and the filename too

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to open the folder in windows explorer from a cell that contains the filename with the path. e.g. I have "C:\files\test.xls" in the ActiveCell, and I want to open the "C:\files" folder in windows explorer, that contains the "test.xls" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shell "explorer.exe " & Left$(ActiveCell.Text, InStrRev(ActiveCell.Text, "\"))
```

the right part retrieves the folder from the full name. The left part launches the windows explorer in that folder.

Since the path may contain spaces, this version is safer (enclosing the path with additional double-quotes):

```
Shell "explorer.exe """ & Left$(ActiveCell.Text, InStrRev(ActiveCell.Text, "\")) & """"
```